Expected output changes when converting function to custom command
I have this function that fetches all CSS properties and values of an element:
function getAllCssPropertiesAndValues(element: Element) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const propertiesAndValues = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
        const propertyName = style[i]
        const value = style.getPropertyValue(propertyName)
        propertiesAndValues[propertyName] = value
    }

    return propertiesAndValues
}

I simply use it by
cy.get('#my-element').then($el => {
    console.log(getAllCssPropertiesAndValues($el[0]))
})

The output I get in the console is as expected, the CSS properties:

When I try to make it its own custom command, I no longer get the expected CSS properties:

This is the custom command I am working on:
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            getAllCssPropertiesAndValues: typeof getAllCssPropertiesAndValues
        }
    }
}

const getAllCssPropertiesAndValues = (element: Element) => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const propertiesAndValues = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
        const propertyName = style[i]
        const value = style.getPropertyValue(propertyName)
        propertiesAndValues[propertyName] = value
    }

    return propertiesAndValues
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getAllCssPropertiesAndValues', getAllCssPropertiesAndValues)

I'm using the custom command by
cy.get('my-element').then($el => { 
  console.log(cy.getAllCssPropertiesAndValues($el[0])) 
})

Am I perhaps missing or understanding something wrong here?

How are you using the custom command?

I'm using the custom command by cy.get('my-element').then($el => { console.log(cy.getAllCssPropertiesAndValues($el[0])) }) Should be the same way initially if I'm not mistaken.

Using a custom command is ok, but it lacks the ability to retry any CSS that changes.
For example if the page makes an API call and sets CSS display: none if there is nothing to display.
This small app simulates that scenario using a setTimeout() to delay the CSS property change.
<body>
  <div style="display: block"></div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const div = document.querySelector('div')
      div.style.setProperty('display', 'none')
    }, 1000)
  </script>
</body>

If I run a test with the Custom Command, it fails
Cypress.Commands.add('getAllCssPropertiesAndValues', {prevSubject: true},          
  ($element) => {
    const element = $element[0]   
    return getAllCssPropertiesAndValues(element)
  }
)

cy.get('div')
  .getAllCssPropertiesAndValues()
  .its('display')
  .should('eq', 'none')      // expect it to change after 1 second


But if I use a Custom Query, it passes
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('getAllCssPropertiesAndValues', 
  function() {
    return ($element) => {
      const element = $element[0]
      return getAllCssPropertiesAndValues(element)
    }
})

cy.get('div')
  .getAllCssPropertiesAndValues()
  .its('display')
  .should('eq', 'none')


Place the Custom Query in /cypress/support/commands.ts to make it globally available.

The documentation is here Custom Queries.
To summarize the difference, the Custom Query returns an inner function that is repeated each time the assertion fails. The Custom Command only runs once and blocks the retry.
So any custom code that returns a sub-value of the element found by cy.get('#my-element'), whether it's a child element, inner-text, or CSS properties, will work for more scenarios if it is a query rather than a command.

Haven't personally tried using custom queries. From what I understood above, you include the custom query within the script. Is it possible to make it globally available the way I implement the custom command counterpart?

I just presented the two together for convenience, but it can be used the same as the custom command.

The custom command should be type child command to make it work in the same way as say find works in cy.get().find().
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            getAllCssPropertiesAndValues: typeof getAllCssPropertiesAndValues
        }
    }
}

const getAllCssPropertiesAndValues = ($element: jQuery<Element>) => {

    const element = $element[0]   // get the element from jquery

    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    const propertiesAndValues = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
        const propertyName = style[i]
        const value = style.getPropertyValue(propertyName)
        propertiesAndValues[propertyName] = value
    }

    return propertiesAndValues
}

Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getAllCssPropertiesAndValues', 
  {prevSubject: true},            <-- indicates is chained from another cmd
  getAllCssPropertiesAndValues
)

Usage:
cy.get('my-selector').getAllCssPropertiesAndValues().then(css => {
  console.log(css)
})

The element is passed via chain from get() to getAllCssPropertiesAndValues(), i.e there's no need to add it as a parameter.
Same usage as cy.get(this).find(that) - with custom commands the Cypress pipeline passes data as the "subject" down the chain.

Tried adding the { prevSubject: true } and changing the parameter to ($element: jQuery<Element>). I'm getting a jQuery' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof jQuery and is asking for an argument on usage?

I think it would work with capital first letter JQuery<HTMLElement>.

For proper types, refer to cypress.d.ts - get<E extends Node = HTMLElement>(selector: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<JQuery<E>>

Cypress commands do not return their values in the same way that standard JS functions do. Cypress commands that return a value return a variable of type Chainable<T>, with the T being the type of the returned value from within the command. Take this example:
/// Defining command
Cypress.Commands.add('returnOne', () => {
  return 1;
});

// foo has a type of Chainable<number>
const foo = cy.returnOne();

In order to properly access the values that are wrapped by the Chainable, you'll need to "unwrap" it. This can easily be done by using cy.then() on the value returned.
// Using the above example
cy.returnOne().then((one) => {
  console.log(one);
});

// Or your code
cy.get('my-element').then($el => { 
  cy.getAllCssPropertiesAndValues($el[0]).then((props) => {
    console.log(props)
  })
})

There are probably additional issues with the sync/async nature of Cypress command chains, but the overarching issue I see is trying to console.log() a Chainable.

I tried unwrapping using the cy.getAllCssPropertiesAndValues($el[0]).then, it's returning an error on the second .then -- Property 'then' does not exist on type '{}'.

Is that a TypeScript compiler error?

I'm not sure but that's the error it's giving me pointing to the inner .then
